# Multiple random trials, each with a confidence interval

Tags: probability, statistics, confidence-interval

Say I calculate the probability $P(A)$ that an event $A$ will happen, and obtain the associated confidence interval $z_1$. If I have $n$ trials, the expected number of trials that will have resulted in the event $A$ happening is $n\cdot P(A)$. But what then is the confidence interval $z_2$ for this expected number of $A$ events?

If the outcomes of each of the trials $n$ are completely correlated, I would imagine the confidence interval $z_2$ would be $z_1$ multiplied by $n$. However, it isn't clear what it would be for zero correlation or partial correlation. Is this a trivially simple problem?

Comment: If the outcomes are independent, you can use the binomial distribution for your interval, and a normal approximation for large $n$

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you are asking. Here is information that
may be helpful.

If $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n, p),$ is the number of Successes observed in
$n$ *independent* trials and $p$ is the probability of Success on any one trial,
then $\hat p = X/n$ is the point estimate of $p.$ A Wald 95% confidence
interval (CI) for $p$ is of the form
$$\hat p \pm 1.96\sqrt{\frac{\hat p(1-\hat p)}{n}},$$

Multiplying through by $n$, you would have the following 95% CI for $E(X)$:
$$X \pm 1.96\sqrt{n\hat p(1-\hat p)}.$$

*Notes:*

(1) As @Henry Comments, these formulas depend on a normal approximation to a binomial
distribution. They work best when $n$ is large and $p$ is not too far from 1/2.
A common approximate rule of thumb is that $np$ and $n(1-p)$ should both
exceed 5.

(2) The Agresti CI for $p$ is more accurate, particularly when $n < 500$ or so:
Define $\tilde n = n+4$ and $\tilde p = (p+2)/\tilde n.$ Then compute the
CI for $p$ as:

$$\tilde p \pm 1.96\sqrt{\frac{\tilde p(1-\tilde p)}{\tilde n}},$$